# SQL Order by for Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-order-by

I am attempting to order this 1 date column. I tried to sort this within the subquery and also outside the subquery but nothing is working. What am I missing? "order by e.[forecast finish]"

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (
      SELECT Convert(varchar(10), cast(e.[forecast finish]  as date), 101) 
      FROM [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_Milestones] e
      WHERE e.[Activity] like '4.7.%'
      AND e.[job nbr] = c.[job nbr]
    ) as "Real Estate Finished" 

FROM [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_JobSiteAddress] c
INNER JOIN [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OneView_Client_Property] d on c.[OVCPID] = d.[OneViewClientPropertyID]
INNER JOIN [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_ProjectDetails] a on a.[job nbr] = c.[job nbr]
INNER JOIN [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_DARM] b on b.[job nbr] = c.[job nbr]
INNER JOIN [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_CREM_BasicLeaseDetails] e on left(e.[TenureID],4) = c.[Client Facility Nbr]
WHERE
b.[Comments] is not null
AND e.[leaseEndDate] = (
     SELECT
        max([LeaseEndDate]) 
     FROM [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_CREM_BasicLeaseDetails] f
     WHERE f.[PropertyKey] = e.[PropertyKey]
)
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data with desired output?

Comment: Man that is hard to read.  Moving on.

Comment: @Paparazzi - I've edited it for you :) the 3 part naming makes it a bit verbose still though.

Comment: Just join to [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_Milestones] and don't double book e.  Then just sort on the date.   Still hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Outside the subquery, you can't see the table `[CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_Milestones]` which was alias'ed as 'e' since it is in the subquery.

The order in a sub-query will not be preserved by the engine, it will sort based on the rest of the plan / joins which can alter it.

You should be able to order on the outside but you would have to `order by"Real Estate Finished"`

Just as a note - given a choice, I wouldn't use field names with spaces, you will end up regretting it longer term. You also shoule review if 3 part names is necessary here, it might be but should be properly considered and not used by default.

The subquery at the top also doesn't appear like it needs to be a sub-query - you should be able to just join to [CDW_CNA].[ssdv].[vw_OVP_Milestones].